# wp_kses allow checkbox class and checked

Tags: theme-development, ajax, escaping, wp-kses

I'm having a hard time getting `wp_kses` to allow the class for an input. These approaches didn't work:

```
input'    => array( 
  'type'  => true, 
  'class' => true, 
  'name'  => true, 
  'value' => true, 
  'id'    => true 
),
```

also with `array()` for class it still is not returned.

Checked is also filtered.

Why do I need this? Well, long story short, the input is in a table which needs to be escaped prior to being printed with echo or with ajax.

Comment: for example:
`return array('table' => array( 'class' => true, 'id' => true ),
    'input' => array( 'type' => true, 'class' => true / array(), 'name' => true, 'value' => true, 'id' => true )`

for table the class is preserved, for input it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the codex, you should define your [**`wp_kses`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) list of allowed html elements as below with `array()` instead of `true`

```
$allowed_html = array(
    'input' => array(
        'type'      => array(),
        'name'      => array(),
        'value'     => array(),
        'checked'   => array()
    ),
);
```

Comment: If only you had read my question

Comment: From [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L1760](core) class and id are already defined in the allowed global attributes. Not sure why it isn't working for you

Comment: Thanks, your observation saved the day! My mistake was a missing space that I didn't notice and was being printed right next to the class, like:

`<input type="checkbox" class="myclass"checked>` and this of course was invalidating the attribute. It was a corner case obviously.